# How to deploy and manage multiple custom python cli tools in docker containers?

Tags: python, docker, architecture, command-line-interface, system-administration

I was hoping to get input into a python design problem that I am facing at work.

My team is currently developing end-user facing utility CLI tools in Python for our data scientists to use, the tools mostly automate system actions/interactions that we are trying to abstract away from users. We think in total we will have something like 20-30 of such python tools to maintain. Within the system the data scientists are able to work in a number of pre-defined docker containers; namely:

- a RHEL container with SAS installed
- a Ubuntu-Focal container with R installed
- a Ubuntu-Focal container with Python installed

That is, users can create & delete new containers at will based upon their current task. I.e. if they want to run their project from scratch they may delete their current container and re-load a fresh new one.

Our key design challenge is how to deploy/install our utility tools into those containers whilst also respecting some key constraints that we think are important to ensure a good UX, namely:

- Avoiding having to have the users manually install our tools as many of our users have 0 knowledge of python / shebangs
- Avoiding having to have users restart their containers if the tool is updated. I.e. we want to be able to update our tools and make those updates available to users with no /little action from the end user
- Having a process for upgrading to new versions of python for our tools as older versions of python become retired/no longer supported (we expect the system to live for 10-15 years).
- Allow tool developers to have freedom to select which python modules and corresponding module versions their tools use without having to worry / be constrained by what other tools have used.
- Ensuring that tools can run on multiple OS’s i.e. as stated above at the very least we need our tools to run on Focal and RHEL

We would be super grateful if anyone has any ideas that could help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to approach this problem, and the best solution will likely depend on your specific needs and constraints.

One option would be to create a custom Python virtual environment for each tool, and then install the tool into that environment. This would allow each tool to have its own set of dependencies, and would also make it easy to upgrade to new versions of Python as needed.

Another option would be to use a tool like Docker Compose to manage your different tools. This would allow you to define each tool as a separate service, and then easily deploy and update them as needed.

Finally, you could also use a tool like Ansible to manage your different tools. This would allow you to define each tool as an Ansible playbook, and then easily deploy and update them as needed.

Ultimately, the best solution for you will likely depend on your specific needs and constraints. However, all of the options above should be able to meet your requirements.